# Adjust size and position of a PGFplots plot

Tags: tables, pgfplots

I created a 2x2 array where each box contains a subfigure. For three subplots I use `\addplot3` from PGFplots with `colorbar` and in the other, a `\addplot`. Due to the use of `colorbar`, the symmetry of the four subfigures is broken. I would like to know if there is a way to rescale the unique plot such that it will align to the other 3 subfigures with `colorbar`.

Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots,colormaps}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{C{.48\textwidth}C{.48\textwidth}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \subfigure [Subfigure 1] {
 \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, %
               xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/400}, %
               colormap/autumn, %
               colorbar, %
               xmin=0, %
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0, %
       ymax=1, %
              xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}, %
              ] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
}} & 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [Subfigure 2] {
 \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, %
               xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               colormap/cool,
       colorbar,
               xmin=0,%
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0, %
       ymax=1, %
               xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}, %
              ] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
}} \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \subfigure [Subfigure 3] {
 \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[tiny,
       xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
       height=5.2cm, width=6cm,% improve scaling manually
               xmin=0,%
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0, %
       ymax=1, %
       only marks, %
       mark size=0.1pt, %
               xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}, 
      ]
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }} & 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [Subfigure 4] {
 \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, %
               xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               colormap/cool, %
       colorbar, %                   
       xmin=0, %
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0, %
              ] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
}} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Several options}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Maybe it would be simpler to place the 3rd pgfplot a bit higher:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not recommend using `\resizebox` to get the desired plot size, as this will scale the text as well: Arbitrarily different font sizes on the same page look really unprofessional.

One way to get more precise control over the size of the plots is to use the key `scale only axis`, which specifies that `width` and `height` commands only apply to the axis area without the tick labels, color bars, and titles. Then you can set the `width` to some appropriate value: If you want each plot to fill half the page width, you'll have to use some value smaller than `0.5\textwidth`, as the color bars and labels still need to be accommodated. To get the plots to align nicely, you can pass the options `trim axis left, trim axis right` to the `tikzpicture` environment. This specifies that only the actual plot area will be used for positioning the plots.

[image]

---

If you want to use horizontal color bars below the plots, you can add the option `baseline` to the `tikzpicture` environments. This will align the lower edge of the plots with the text baseline.

[image]

---

Code for alignment with vertical color bars:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots,colormaps}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        scale only axis,
        width=0.25\textwidth,
        xtick={0,0.05,0.1},
    },
    /tikz/every picture/.append style={
        trim axis left,
        trim axis right,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{C{.48\textwidth}C{.48\textwidth}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \subfigure [Subfigure 1] {
  \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90}, %
    xlabel={$p$}, %
    ylabel={Mean}, %
    title={Mean vs $p$}, %
    y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/400}, %
    colormap/autumn, %
    colorbar, %
    xmin=0, %
    xmax=0.1, %
    ymin=0, %
    ymax=1, %
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
} & 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [Subfigure 2] {
 \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, %
               xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               colormap/cool,
       colorbar, 
               xmin=0,%
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0, %
       ymax=1, %
               xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}, %
              ] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
} \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \subfigure [Subfigure 3] {

\begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[
       xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               xmin=0,%
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0, %
       ymax=1, %
       only marks, %
       mark size=0.1pt, %
               xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
      ]
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 } & 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [Subfigure 4] {
 \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, %
               xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               colormap/cool, %
       colorbar, %                   
       xmin=0, %
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0,ymax=1, %
       xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
              ] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Several options}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Code for alignment with horizontal color bars:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots,colormaps}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        scale only axis,
        width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.23\textwidth,
        xtick={0,0.05,0.1},
    },
    /tikz/every picture/.append style={
        trim axis left,
        trim axis right,
        baseline
    }
}
\begin{document}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{C{.48\textwidth}C{.48\textwidth}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \subfigure [Subfigure 1] {
  \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90}, %
    xlabel={$p$}, %
    ylabel={Mean}, %
    title={Mean vs $p$}, %
    y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/400}, %
    colormap/autumn, %
    colorbar horizontal, %
    xmin=0, %
    xmax=0.1, %
    ymin=0, %
    ymax=1, %
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
} & 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [Subfigure 2] {
 \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, %
               xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               colormap/cool,
       colorbar horizontal, 
               xmin=0,%
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0, %
       ymax=1, %
               xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}, %
              ] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
} \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \subfigure [Subfigure 3] {

\begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[
       xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               xmin=0,%
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0, %
       ymax=1, %
       only marks, %
       mark size=0.1pt, %
               xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
      ]
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 } & 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subfigure [Subfigure 4] {
 \begin{tikzpicture} %
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, %
               xlabel={$p$}, %
           ylabel={Mean}, %
               title={Mean vs $p$}, %
               colormap/cool, %
       colorbar horizontal, %                   
       xmin=0, %
               xmax=0.1, %
       ymin=0,ymax=1, %
       xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
              ] %
  \end{axis} %
 \end{tikzpicture}
} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Several options}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added something to my LaTeX document and the line /tikz/every picture/.append style generate a problem. Is it possible to define a style and call it each time it is needed instead of global?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about this. What problem does it generate (what's the error message)? What code did you use exactly? Most importantly, what are you trying to achieve?